# Cadastrando várias imagens em uma postagem

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, imagem

Estou com um projeto de estudo que tem que criar uma espécie de galeria. Supondo que eu tenha um limite de 20 imagens por postagem. Como cadastrar essas imagens no banco de dados?

Eu pensei em duas hipóteses. Na 1º eu criaria cerca de 22 colunas em uma tabela chamada `postagens`, seria algo do tipo `ID TITULO IMG1 IMG2 IMG3 IMG4` e por ai em diante. Só que acho que não é a melhor forma, devido ao fato de ser inúmeras colunas, e nem sempre todas elas serão preenchidas. Por um lado eu ia poder trabalhar com cada imagem individualmente.

Na 2º hipótese eu pensei em apenas 3 colunas, algo como `ID TITULO CONTEÚDO`. Esse `Conteúdo` seria o código em HTML da postagem inteira, só que nessa hipótese eu fico limitado, pois não dará pra trabalhar com cada imagem individualmente.

Estou em dúvida entre essas duas hipóteses. Existe alguma 3º 4º ou 5º? Lembrando que o projeto trabalha diretamente com imagens, então a maleabilidade em relação a administração das fotos é um ponto crucial

Comment: Qual o problema com múltiplas colunas e campos vazios? Ter que ficar destrinchando HTML para puxar informação não tem muito sentido...

Comment: Pensando bem, acho que você já sabe o que é melhor entre a opção 1 e 2. E o que está procurando é a opção 3, 4 ou 5, mas aí acho que seria melhor você apresentar um design básico do DB e quais problemas tem com ele. . . . Chegou a conferir os arquivos do site? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+imagens+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Vlw @brasofilo. Eu realmente preferi a 1º opção, só que eu achei essa hipotese meio invialvel, porque pensei que podia ser espaços inúteis demasiados.

Comment: @brasofilo, arrumei uma 3º alternativa. Sempre que fizer o upload das imagens, o codigo vai criar uma pasta de nome unico, e no BD vai cadastrar tipo o ID || Titulo || Nome da pasta || Imagem de Capa. Ai quando eu clicar na postagem, o php vai pegar o nome da pasta referente aquela post e vai listar tudo. Funciono EXATAMENTE como eu queria. E bem simples.

Comment: @brasofilo isso que você falo também é uma boa, e é algo simples também né. Nao tinha pensando nisso. E olha que eu já fiz isso em, só era em um sistema de comentários.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é fazer tipo o WordPress faz, numa tabela se armazenam os dados do *post* e em outra os meta-dados de cada um. Na verdade, o WP trata a imagem como se fosse um *post* e a associa com um outro *post* específico usando a coluna `post_parent`.

Uma opção simplificada:

- tabela POSTS

  ```
  ID          TITLE           CONTENT
  id-post     titulo-post     conteúdo-post
  ```
- tabela IMAGENS

  ```
  ID          POST_ID         URL
  id-imagem   id-post         info-imagem
  ```

Ou uma mais parecida ao WordPress:

- tabela POSTS

  ```
  ID          TITLE           CONTENT         TYPE            PARENT
  id-post     titulo-post     conteúdo-post   tipo-de-post    idPost-ou-zero
  ```
- tabela META

  ```
  ID          POST_ID         META_TYPE       META_VALUE
  id-meta     id-post         tipo-de-meta    valor-do-meta(url,exif,etc)
  ```